# What's currently best practice for hiding H1s?

Tags: html, css, html-heading

This has always been something that's not very clear.

I've previously used the `text-indent:-9999px;` trick but I see on the W3Schools site on the `visibility:hidden` and `display:none` page they use the H1 as an example.

[W3Schools CSS Display](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp)

This was something I alway thought was a big no-no from an SEO point of view.

Comment: There are many recommended practices in that debacle of a resource that are contrary to 'best practice.' Any Google search that throws up (pun intended) that site as the number one link should prompt you to look further down the page to results from [Mozilla Developer Network](http://developer.mozilla.com).

Comment: Are you talking about an `h1` where you want to 'replace' the text with an image?

Comment: Not exactly, I know you can do this for the logo, but other pages have their own H1s so it can't be site wide.

Comment: The big no-no here is that you're reading w3schools.

Comment: **Please note** It is **NOT** a W3C site and is in no way affiliated with them. Please look at [w3fools](http://w3fools.com) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'best practise', it doesn't matter. With all the methods you talked about the object will still be in the DOM. This means that spiders will crawl it with all of the methods you talked about:

- text-indent:-9999px;
- display:none;
- visibility:hidden;